# With Java 17, JUnit5, is there a way to always launch a test with a Java Agent?

Tags: java, junit, eclipselink, junit5, javaagents

We need to make sure we always launch several Java JUnit5 tests with EclipseLink as a Java Agent. This is because these test will do some JPA dynamic queries and EclipseLink needs to do some class weaving in order to function.

In Maven, we fixed this by by supplying `argLine` to the surefire and failsafe plugins pointing at the EclipseLink jar.

However, it's royal pain the butt for running the tests out of the IDE... where you have to setup a profile for each test to launch with the agent in tow.

I'm hoping there's a simple annotation that we can annotate our tests with to do this, but I've come up empty in my search. Thank you for any help, or any pointers were someone has at least done something similar where we could modify their approach to work for us.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA should import `argLine` from Maven Surefire or Failsafe and add them automatically to your run configuration. (Attention: AFAIR, if you set it for both plugins, it will import both, which is a known problem.) What is "the IDE" in your case?

Comment: Both IntelliJ and Eclipse users. However, the argLine has to be disabled as that is for Maven only and that behavior is undesired because it interferes with other functions of the IDE.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You said you want tests in the IDE to run like in Maven, now you are saying the exact opposite. Maybe make up your mind, would you please?

Comment: Are you ok? that's a little aggressive.

Comment: I am doing great, and I am still willing to help you. I just want to avoid to chase my tail, because you do not tell me clearly what you want and what the actual problem is. If that is too aggressive for you, feel free to help yourself.

Comment: I appreciate the help. 

To explain: argLine is _strictly_ used for maven builds. Eclipse and IntelliJ _should_ ignore it, as they have their own build systems internally. IntelliJ's feature can be useful, but in this case it is not desired because the argLine does things like invoking other processes that are not relevant to IDE users. So, it would be useful if junit tests universally could specify a Java agent to use, which solves the problem for all scenarios. I hope that helps

Comment: So, this is actually strictly an IntelliJ question, is it not? I think that your approach to use Maven on the one hand and import the project into IntelliJ but then on the other hand to expect the IDE to ignore (part of) the Maven settings is kind of weird and basically asking for trouble - the same trouble you are in today. I use Maven in many projects, big and small, and also Java agents. I always strive to configure the Maven build in such a way that it works as seamlessly as possible in the IDE with Maven being the leading system, not the IDE. I warmly recommend you to do the same.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, you may want to experiment with [run/debug configuration templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#config-folders) and add the java agent to the JVM parameters in your template. If this comment helps, let me know, then I can convert it into an answer and add a bit more text and a few screenshots.

Comment: >  the Maven settings is kind of weird and basically asking for trouble
I disagree. There are a ton of things that happen during a build that aren't relevant to an IDE. An IDE implies "I" for integrated, meaning it has it's own build system. The ArgLine is a neat party trick by IntelliJ, but it's a trick nonetheless. For instance, do you want JaCoCo to be enabled EVERY time you build?

Comment: That is what Maven profiles are for. Even in my most complex project, Maven is always the leading system. Depending on the build profiles I select, my IDE does more or less when building or running code. This is not a discussion forum, so if you choose to reject my advice, I am fine with that. But then, like I said, you are on your own, trying to use Maven and importing it into IDEA on the one hand, but then on the other hand expecting different behaviour in both. Good luck, I am out of here.